# How do I structure this many-to-many-to-many relationship in the most "eloquent" way?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I can imagine a few ways to do this but I want to make sure I'm doing things efficiently and in a Laravel-optimized way.

I've got Users and Teams. Users can belong to many teams,  and of course a team can have many users. A typical many-to-many:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function teams()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Team');
    }
}
```

and,

```
class Team extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

I also want each user to have a "status" within each team. Eg, "Active" and "Inactive".

Do I create a third table/model for "Status", and set up pivots to both Users and Teams? If so, How do I use eloquent to efficiently fetch users of a given status for each team?

Is there a different approach I should consider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With many-to-many you obviously require an intermediate table. `team_user` be it. And you can add the `status` column to this table.

```
team_id    user_id    status
1          1          Active
2          1          Inactive
....
```

**Relations:**

```
public function teams()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Team')->withPivot('status');
}
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withPivot('status');
}
```

And,

```
$users=User::with('teams')->get();
foreach($users as $user)
{
   foreach($user->teams as $team)
   {
        echo $team->pivot->status;
   }
}
```

Here is doc for [Working with pivot tables](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables)

Comment: Ahh, thanks Sanzeeb. I didn't know I could add the status info in the pivot table itself. I'll give this a try in the next day and report back.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!